# Formatting For Parameters in Doxygen

Tags: c++, c++11, documentation, doxygen

I am using this method to document my methods:

```
/**
* Order beers from another player and add them into own inventory.
* @params from The Player who has to deliver the order
*/

void Player::order(const int numberOfBeers, Player &from)
{
    from.decreaseInventory(numberOfBeers);
    increaseInventory(numberOfBeers);
}
```

When I check my output files, I just get this in such a format:

```
Order beers from another player and add them into own inventory. from The Player who has to deliver the order
```

This looks very unstructured. There's no separation for parameters. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doxygen to ducument parameters is `\param` not \params`(so without`s`).

See: http://doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam, excerpts:

> Starts a parameter description for a function parameter with name , followed by a description of the parameter. The existence of the parameter is checked and a warning is given if the documentation of this (or any other) parameter is missing or not present in the function declaration or definition.
>
> The \param command has an optional attribute, dir, specifying the direction of the parameter. Possible values are "[in]", "[in,out]", and "[out]", note the [square] brackets in this description. When a parameter is both input and output, [in,out] is used as attribute.
>
> The parameter description is a paragraph with no special internal structure. All visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph.
>
> Multiple adjacent \param commands will be joined into a single paragraph. Each parameter description will start on a new line. The \param description ends when a blank line or some other sectioning command is encountered.